# Will not create a class template for c++

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-data-type

I am trying to figure out how to use classes with class template and I get these errors:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall AdtBag::AdtBag(void)" (??0?$AdtBag@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main  C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ADTBagAddition\ADTBagAddition\Source.obj    ADTBagAddition

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall AdtBag::~AdtBag(void)" (??1?$AdtBag@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ADTBagAddition\ADTBagAddition\Source.obj    ADTBagAddition

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall AdtBag::store_in_bag(int)" (?store_in_bag@?$AdtBag@H@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function _main C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ADTBagAddition\ADTBagAddition\Source.obj    ADTBagAddition

Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall AdtBag::whats_in_bag(void)" (?whats_in_bag@?$AdtBag@H@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main  C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ADTBagAddition\ADTBagAddition\Source.obj    ADTBagAddition

Error   5   error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ADTBagAddition\Debug\ADTBagAddition.exe ADTBagAddition

Here is my code:

source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AdtBag.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    AdtBag<int> BagInt;
    int a = 78;
    cout << "Int Bag Contains: " << endl;
    BagInt.store_in_bag ( a );
    cout << BagInt.whats_in_bag () << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

AdtBag.h

```
#ifndef __ADTBAG__
#define __ADTBAG__

template<class ItemType>
class AdtBag {
private:
    ItemType in_bag;
public:
    AdtBag<ItemType> ();
    ~AdtBag<ItemType> ();

    void store_in_bag ( ItemType into_bag );
    ItemType whats_in_bag ();
};

#endif
```

AdtBag.cpp

```
#include "AdtBag.h"

template <class ItemType>
AdtBag<ItemType>::AdtBag () {
}

template <class ItemType>
AdtBag<ItemType>::~AdtBag () {
}

template<class ItemType>
void AdtBag<ItemType>::store_in_bag ( ItemType into_bag ) {
    in_bag = into_bag;
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType AdtBag<ItemType>::whats_in_bag () {
    return in_bag;
}
```

Why is this producing the error messages? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 if that matters. I thought I did everything correctly, but I guess not. Any suggestions?

Comment: All your templated definitions need to go in the header file.

Comment: Also, you have undefined behaviour due to using an identifier that starts with two underscores as your include guard.

Comment: The importance of Daniel's comment cannot be stressed strongly enough.

Comment: This was a different question because i didn't know that templates can only be implemented in the header file, which i didn't know until now. So the answer to my question is that templates can only be implemented in the header file. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: It's not quite true: if they are only used by one compilation unit, then the whole lot can go in a source file. Some firms even adopt a tpp extension for template code.

Comment: For my class I have to have each class outside of the source file, so I must use the header file.

Comment: And fix those include guards - the compiler might eat your cat if you don't!

Comment: Should it be just one underscore then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loosely speaking, all template class code must be in the header.

Essentially, this is because template code is only compiled when a template is instantiated for some type.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware that the implementation must be within the same header file.